# function on the new woocommerce 2.6.4

Tags: function, woocommerce

i updated my woocommerce to 2.6.2 to 2.6.4

and some functions in my function.php fils seems not working anymore

this that display SOLD instead of out of stok on my theme

```
function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
//change text "In Stock' to 'SPECIAL ORDER'
if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] =   __('AVAILABLE', 'woocommerce');

//change text "Out of Stock' to 'SOLD OUT'
if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('SOLD', 'woocommerce');
return $availability;
```

is someone have an idea why this doesn't work anymore?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to check plugin files.

Comment: What filter are you targeting? Can you add the rest of your code, you appear to be missing an `add_filter()`. It's unlikely that Woo would have dropped back-compatibility from 2.6.2 to 2.6.4 as something like that would normally be in a bigger update (like when 2.0 broke a lot of templates).